# How to join many-to-many relations in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine, join

I've got some entities:

Supplier:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blah\Blah\ApiClientBundle\Entity\SupplierRepository")
 */
class Supplier
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blah\SopBundle\Entity\SupplierUser", mappedBy="suppliers")
     */
    protected $users;

    [...]
}
```

SupplierUser:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SupplierUserRepository")
 */
class SupplierUser
{
    [...]

        /**
         * @var ArrayCollection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Blah\Blah\ApiClientBundle\Entity\Supplier", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="supplier_user_supplier",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="supplier_id")}
         * )
         * @Assert\Valid()
         */
        protected $suppliers;

    [...]
}
```

Now in one repository I join the entities mentioned above to one report (rpr):

```
public function findBrandsBySupplierUser(SupplierUser $supplierUser)
{
    return array_column(
        $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('rpr')
            ->join(Supplier::class, 's', 'WITH', 's.supplierId = rpr.supplierId')
            ->join(SupplierUser::class, 'su')
            ->where('su = :supplierUser')
            ->setParameters([
                'supplierUser' => $supplierUser,
            ])
            ->select('rpr.brand')
            ->distinct()
            ->orderBy('rpr.brand')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult(),
        'brand'
    );
}
```

But the result is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r0_.brand AS brand_0 FROM returnable_products_report r0_ 
INNER JOIN supplier s1_ ON (s1_.supplier_id = r0_.supplier_id)
INNER JOIN supplier_user s2_
WHERE s2_.user_id = ?
ORDER BY r0_.brand ASC
```

So I receive a Cartesian join. Why doesn't Doctrine join automatically?

I could opt for enforcing the the join fields, but I don't know how exactly to do it. How should `join(SupplierUser::class, 'su')` look in such case?

Comment: Show entity definition for `rpr`

Comment: Well, I cannot add tons of code here. Stack overflow enforces some proportion of code to text. Is there some part that is interesting for you? The supplier_id is just an id without relation. That's why I join like `join(Supplier::class, 's', 'WITH', 's.supplierId = rpr.supplierId')`.

Comment: You should define mapping for supplier in your related entity and then perform join using mapped property

Answer (score 0):

The working answer seems to be:

```
->join('s.users', 'su')
```

instead of

```
->join(SupplierUser::class, 'su')
```